# How to set background color programmatically from an app color theme

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set background color programmatically for a  element, which should be same as

```
<TableRow android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">
```

in xml file.
For now on I'm stuck with

```
 row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ffff"));
```

, but I dont know how to pass "@color/colorPrimaryDark" here correctly and can't find any relative information in Android documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting background colors programmatically is easy:

```
row.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
```

For more information:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setBackgroundResource(int)

Answer (score 1):

This will set the backgroud with alpha

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#c0ffffff")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```